# Please explain this to me why is the second alert not showing

Tags: javascript, jquery

It seems that the second alert in the code posted below will not appear; the `alert("The user is succesfully been added!");` will not show. I have a script for every text box as for username, firstname, lastname and password.

First I tried doing separate alert for the save btn and textbox; scenario is when I click the save button with empty fields it will show the alert with success that the user is added. then it will show another alert that I need to fill up the textbox. So I was thinking that if I check for empty field the success alert would not show and it will only show when I input correct things. but what happened is that it will not show the alert that I was expecting to show.

Code for the whole add user form:

```
<div id="add_user" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel"
     aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="alert alert-info"><strong>Add User</strong></div>
        <form class="form-horizontal" method="post">
            <div class="control-group">
                <label class="control-label" for="inputEmail">Username</label>
                <div class="controls">
                    <input type="text" id="inputEmail" name="username" placeholder="Username" required>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="control-group">
                <label class="control-label" for="inputPassword">Password</label>
                <div class="controls">
                    <input type="password" name="password" id="inputPassword" placeholder="Password" required>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="control-group">
                <label class="control-label" for="inputEmail">Firstname</label>
                <div class="controls">
                    <input type="text" id="inputEmail" name="firstname" placeholder="Firstname" pattern="[A-Za-z].{1,}"
                           required>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="control-group">
                <label class="control-label" for="inputEmail">Lastname</label>
                <div class="controls">
                    <input type="text" id="inputEmail" name="lastname" placeholder="Lastname" pattern="[A-Za-z].{1,}"
                           required>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="control-group">
                <div class="controls">
                    <button name="submit" onClick="return saveuservalidation()" class="btn btn-success"><i
                            class="icon-save icon-large"></i>&nbsp;Save
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true"><i class="icon-remove icon-large"></i>&nbsp;Close
        </button>
    </div>
</div>
<script>
    function saveuservalidation() {
        if (firstname == "" || lastname == "" || username == "" || password == "") {
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
            alert("The user is succesfully been added!");
        }
    }
</script>
<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
$username=$_POST['username'];
$password=$_POST['password'];
$firstname=$_POST['firstname'];
$lastname=$_POST['lastname'];

mysql_query("insert into users (username,password,firstname,lastname) values('$username','$password','$firstname','$lastname')")or die(mysql_error());
}
?>
```

The javascript: (is this the right way or not?)

```
<script>
    function saveuservalidation() {
        if (firstname == "" || lastname == "" || username == "" || password == "") {
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
            alert("The user is succesfully been added!");
        }
    }
</script>
```

OR

```
<script>
    function saveuservalidation() {
        if (firstname == "" || lastname == "" || username == "" || password == "") {
            return false;
        } else {
            alert("The user is succesfully been added!");
            return true;
        }
    }
</script>
```

It will not show any alert.

Answer (score 4):

As soon as you `return`, the function returns and everything thereafter isn't executed (is unreachable). Change it to

```
else{
   alert("The user is succesfully been added!"); 
   return true;
}
```

and the alert will be shown.

Comment: Is one of the fields you are checking for empty? @Chouny

Comment: When you press save in adding a user it will prompt an alert that you would fill in the textbox after filling up everything correctly it should show the the second alert; The first that I have done is that I did a separate alert for the textbox and the save button like this when you click save with empty fields it will show an alert that the user is added then a prompt will show in the textbox that you need to fill up the field require. I was thinking that if i check for empty box the alert successfully added will not show and it did but when i save w/ correct input it will not show thealert